# Create Multidex Application with Adobe Flash Builder

Tags: android, air, flash-builder, android-multidex

I have an Actionscript Mobile project that I'm working on in flash builder 4.7 with quite a few ANEs included. The most recent one has pushed us over the 65k method reference limit. I can't find a way to properly include or implement the multidex support library with the app. Has anyone ever done this with flash builder before?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I've just encountered the same issue with a client project.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.  **manifestAdditions** block doesn't allot setting MultiDex.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to try dynamically load second dex file at application start and then load classes at runtime via [Java-Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html):

**Take a look at these resources:**

- [Post on Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.by/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html)
- [Sample Project](https://github.com/yigit/secondary-dex-example)

Be sure that after packaging AIR application your jar library is placed in assets folder. You can unzip apk in any case and check that it's located where it must be. Also, dex file must be named `classes.dex`.

*For Android 4.x.x DexClassLoader can read only files with .jar extension.

Comment: How do you know which classes to load with Reflection?

Comment: I've packaged them, I see them in jar or in API